# Actualización de datos en una BBDD

Tags: python, sqlite3

estoy intentando hacer un codigo que modifique los datos de un articulo en una BBDD, pero al hacerlo me tira el siguiente error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Franco
```

Tengo entendido que toma el valor que yo le doy a actualizar como si fuera el nombre de la columna

Las columnas que tengo son "ID", "NOMBRE", "APELLIDO", "PASSWORD"

Entonces para probar lo que hago es crear un articulo (el de ID 1) con un nombre random, ej "Jorge", luego intento cambiarlo por otro, en este caso "Franco". Pero al darle el nombre nuevo identifica este como si fuera el nombre de la columna, y no el valor a introducir.
Tengo el codigo de la siguiente forma:

```
lista=[(id_lista, nombre_lista, ape_lista, pass_lista)]

cursoor.execute(f"UPDATE USUARIOS SET NOMBRE={nombre_lista}, APELLIDO={ape_lista}, PASSWORD={pass_lista} WHERE ID={id_lista}")
conexion.commit()
```

No encuentro que puede llegar a estar mal realmente.

(Los datos son ingresados desde una caja de texto de tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Aviso inicial

Para empezar, generar consultas sql usando formateo de cadenas suele no ser buena idea, debido a que hace muy facil la [inyección sql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Generalmente, los diversos motores de bases de datos ofrecen formas de pasar datos a una consulta de forma más segura. En sqlite3, podés usar "?" donde deberían ir los datos (ver más adelante).

#### Explicación del error

Supongamos que tenemos una tabla "tabla" con una columna de tipo int "numero" y una columna de tipo text "letra":

Cuando generas una consulta de esta forma, con numero=1 y letra="a"

```
f"UPDATE tabla SET numero={numero}, letra={letra}"
```

Se termina generando

```
UPDATE tabla SET numero=1, letra=a
```

Con los numeros no hay problema, se generan perfecto, pues los números se expresan así en una consulta sql. El problema son las cadenas. Estas deben de ir entre comillas, de lo contrario, en el mejor de los casos, te pasará lo que te acaba de pasar de que creerá que es un identificador (nombres de tablas, columnas, esquemas, etc).

#### Solución

Probablemente, la solución que piensas a esta altura sería "le pongo comillas alrededor y ya `UPDATE tabla SET letra='{letra}'`". Pero, ten en cuenta mi aviso inicial: No es buena idea crear consultas con formateo de cadenas.

Así, que una solución más sencilla y segura sería:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE tabla SET numero=?, letra=?", (numero, letra))
```

Este sistema, es muy similar al [viejo formateo de cadenas de Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). sqlite3 se encargará automaticamente del tema de las comillas y otros detalles. Lo unico malo es, que si querés pasar un tipo de dato desconocido para sqlite3, tendrás que registrarlo. Pero las ventajas superan las desventajas.

Comment: Agradezco la respuesta elaborada, me sirve un montón para ver los problemas y tenerlos en cuenta a futuro. Lo de las comillas no me habia percatado y al final termine haciendolo como mencionaste a lo ultimo para evitar sql injection.
Se agradece <3

Comment: De nada Kaster, me alegro de haberte ayudado c: